# How can i define something by switch?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to setup a sorter of receiving the messages. However, the following code (actual outcome) is always undefined.

This program is a part of the roulette, in which a command is required to place a bet. The code itself is tried in Google Chrome.

```js
var position;
function positionTypeConverter(betP) {
    if betP > 50 | betP < 0 | betP = NaN {
    throw ('invalid position');
    } else switch (betP) {
    case 1<=betP<=48:
        return position = ' '+betP+', single ';
        break;
    case 0:
        return position = ' zero ';
        break;
    case 49:
        return position = ' independent ';
        break;
    case 50:
        return position = ' LuckyEi ';
        break;




    };
    console.log(this.position);



};
```

by inputting `positionTypeConverter(number)`, 'number' can be anything, it is all the way undefined.
but I would expect the result example of below:
`positionTypeConverter(12)` comes with `12, single`

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Fix those first.

Comment: What is `console.log(this.position)` supposed to do?

Comment: @melpomene it is an outcome

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I made that line to log the result

Comment: First off, that line is never reached. `return` leaves the function. Second, you're logging `this.position`, not `position` or the return value of the function.

Comment: `break` after `default` case is redundant, to actually all the of the break are redundant as you're returning values, so once it hit `return` doesn't go to next line

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not valid Javascript Syntax. Change it as follow

```
function positionTypeConverter(betP) {
  if( betP > 50 || betP < 0 || isNaN(betP)) {
     throw ('invalid position');
  } else { 
    switch (betP) {
    case 0:
        return ' zero ';
    case 49:
        return ' independent ';
    case 50:
        return ' LuckyEi ';
    default: 
        return betP+', single ';
    }
  }
};
```

And if you want to log the result inside the function:

```
function positionTypeConverter(betP) {
  if( betP > 50 || betP < 0 || isNaN(betP)) {
     throw ('invalid position');
  } else { 
    var result = '';

    switch (betP) {
        case 0:
            result = ' zero ';
            break;
        case 49:
            result = ' independent ';
            break;
        case 50:
            result = ' LuckyEi ';
            break;
        default: 
            result = betP+', single ';
    }

    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
};
```

Comment: how can I add an output through console log?

Comment: You should first call this function and then log the output, for example.  `var result = positionTypeConverter(12); console.log(result)`

Comment: `break`after `default` case is redundant, to actually all the of the `break` are redundant as you're returning values, so once it hit `return` doesn't go to next line

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I update the answer.

Comment: that means if no `break` is needed if i use `return`?

Comment: Yup as @Code Maniac said, once your code hit the `return` statement, it doesn't go to the next line. So `break` would be useless. If you are not using `return` you should put `break` tho.

Comment: is that possible to show the outcome (like in console) within the code?

Comment: Yes why not, in that case you can simply replace for example this line `return ' zero ';` with something like this `console.log(' zero ');  break;`. Repeat this for all cases including `default:`.

Comment: but never was `positionTypeConverter` defined even that, even I've changed the code above and replaced the line like return into console.log

Comment: Check the answer again, I added what you want